# Fatal error creating an order in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm calling to a Prestashop Webservice with a petition like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<order>
    <id_address_delivery>1999</id_address_delivery>
    <id_address_invoice>1999</id_address_invoice>
    <id_cart>12102</id_cart>
    <id_currency>1</id_currency>
    <id_lang>1</id_lang>
    <id_customer>1728</id_customer>
    <id_carrier>282</id_carrier>
    <module>cheque</module>
    <payment>NTPM</payment>
    <total_discounts>0</total_discounts>
    <total_paid>4.7999996</total_paid>
    <total_paid_real>4.7999996</total_paid_real>
    <total_products>4.7999996</total_products>
    <total_products_wt>4.363636</total_products_wt>
    <conversion_rate>1</conversion_rate>
    <associations>
        <order_rows>
            <order_row>
                <product_id>12</product_id>
                <product_quantity>1</product_quantity>
            </order_row>
        </order_rows>
    </associations>
</order>
</prestashop>
```

I've checked that If I send all the fields the same error is returned. Only:

```
Fatal error
```

The cart, the address, the customer and the product exist. The article is the same in the cart and is active and has stock too.

The Prestashop version is 1.6.

Comment: I've found that the error comes from the _module_ tag. If the module name is not present the API doesn't show an error. Only a _Fatal error_ is sended.

Answer (score 1):

Today I experience the same error and the solution for us was setting to the cart the id of the created customer and also the secure_key. Because PaymentModule class check if secure_key from customer and content->cart->secure_key fields match before create the order.

I hope these can help.